# Problem with invoking the verifyIPN() function

Tags: php, html, sql

it's been days, weeks that I can not solve a problem.. I get straight to the point, I used some codes to be able to integrate the ipn of PayPal with my website, through php. Everything seems to go smoothly except the recall of the result of the public function verifyIPN(), in the file response.php, the variable $verified does not work as it should, does not even let me enter the if to perform the insert operations in the db, practically it is as if a "false" value returned, when it should return "true". I hope I have been clear. Thanks in advance!

**notify.php**

```
public function verifyIPN()
{
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }

        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }

        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'User-Agent: PHP-IPN-Verification-Script',
            'Connection: Close',
        ));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }

        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**RESPONSE.PHP**

```
<?php 
require('notify.php');
use PaypalIPN;

$ipn = new PaypalIPN();

$ipn->useSandbox();

$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();

if ($verified) { 

}
```

Comment: What is `$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');` doing?

Comment: I don't know sincerely

Comment: Havent you got some sort of debugger to look at the values of the variables ?

Comment: Mmm I tried some prints but the variable is as if it were empty, it does not give me errors